# Defining the symmetric product of elliptic curves without knowing how to take a quotient by a finite group action

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I know this is a bit of an odd request, but I am looking to construct the natural map $E^n\to E^{(n)}$ as schemes without knowing how to take a quotient by a finite group action, and do it in a relatively understandable way. My goal in doing this is to show the construction to some fellow graduate students who know some basics of algebraic geometry, but not enough to know how to take a quotient yet. (I'm presenting in a seminar which has some interesting rules about what you must be able to show and what you have to be able to cover.)

It would be enough to do this in the case $n=2$ (and maybe $n=3$, but let's stick with $n=2$ to start). Here I know that $E^{(2)}$ is a ruled surface over $E$ (in fact, $E^{(n)}$ is a $\Bbb P^{n-1}$-bundle over $E$ by some general theory), so I should be able to give a morphism $E^2\to E^{(2)}$ via a line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ on $E^2$ and a surjection from the locally free sheaf $f^*\mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{L}$ where $E^{(2)}=\Bbb P(\mathcal{F})$ and $f:E^2\to E^{(2)}\to E$ is the composite map. From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4635033/for-an-elliptic-curve-e-how-can-we-describe-canonical-divisor-or-addition-o?rq=1), $E^{(2)}$ is the unique ruled surface of invariant $-1$, $\mathcal{F}$ is a nontrivial extension of $\mathcal{O}_E$ and $\mathcal{O}_E(P)$, and the composite map $E^2\to E$ is multiplication.

If I knew about the quotient map $E^2\to E^{(2)}$, I could say that $f^*\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{L}$ should be the pullback of $\pi^*\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{O}_{E^{(2)}}(1)\cong\mathcal{O}_{E^{(2)}}(\sigma_P(E))$ where $\sigma_P:E\to E^{(2)}$ is the natural section given from the surjection $\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{O}_E(P)$, but going the other way is giving me trouble - it's hard for me to come up with a good way to write down what this map is. I'm looking for ways to specify this map, or alternate ways to construct the map $E^2\to E^{(2)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following. Let $\alpha:E\times E\to E$ be the addition map. Let $D\subseteq E\times E$ be the divisor $E\times 0+0\times E$. Then I claim that the adjunction map $\phi:\alpha^*\alpha_*({\cal O}(D))\to{\cal O}(D)$ is a surjection and that $\alpha_*({\cal O}(D))$ is locally free of rank $2$. I also claim that the corresponding map $q:E\times E\to {\bf P}(\alpha_*({\cal O}(D)))=P$
identifies $q$ with the quotient map under the involution swapping the factors (so that
$P=E^{(2)}$).

To establish the first claim, let $I:E\times E\to E\times E$ be the map $(a,b)\mapsto (a,a+b)$. This is obviously
an isomorphism. We then have $I(D)=\Delta+0\times E$, where $\Delta$ is the diagonal of $E\times E$. If we let $\pi:E\times E\to E$ be the second
projection, we then have $\pi\circ I=\alpha.$ Now for any $b\in E$, the pull-back of $I(D)$ to ${E\times b}$ is
$(b,b)+(0,b)$. This is an effective divisor of degree $2$ on $E\times b\simeq E$ and so
its linear system is of dimension $2$ (by Riemann-Roch) and ${\cal O}((b,b)+(0,b))$ has no cohomology
in non zero degree. Also, the linear system of $(b,b)+(0,b)$ is base-point free (see Hartshorne Cor. IV.3.2).
So, by the semicontinuity theorem, we see that  the adjunction map
$\pi^*\pi_*({\cal O}(I(D)))\to{\cal O}(I(D))$ is surjective and that $\pi_*({\cal O}(I(D)))$
is of rank $2$. Applying $I^{*}$ to this we get the first claim.

Now let $\sigma:E\times E\to E\times E$ be the map swapping the factors.
We have $\sigma(D)=D$, so the map $\phi$ is $\sigma$-equivariant.

Note that the action
of $\sigma$ on $\alpha_*({\cal O}(D))$ is trivial. To show this, apply the relative Lefschetz trace formula
(one could also do this directly by applying $I$ and computing on one fibre of $\pi$). The fixed point set of $\sigma$ is $\Delta\simeq E$, and one obtains
the formula
$$
{\rm Trace}(\sigma,\alpha_*({\cal O}(D)))=
{1\over 2}{\rm Trace}([2]_*({\cal O}(2\cdot 0)))={1\over 2}4=2
$$
and so the action of $\sigma$ on $\alpha_*({\cal O}(D))$ has to be trivial, since its
eigenvalues are all $\pm 1$ (here the $0$ in $2\cdot 0$ is the origin of $E$).

So we conclude that the fibres of the map $q:E\times E\to {\bf P}(\alpha_*({\cal O}(D)))=P$
induced by $\phi$ are $\sigma$-invariant. Note that the map $q$ is not constant on any fibre
of $\alpha$, since the restriction of $D$ to any fibre of $\alpha$ is effective of degree $2$.
Also, since the degree of the restriction of ${\cal O}_{P}(1)$ to any fibre of $P$ over $E$ is
$1$ and the degree of the restriction of $D$ to any fibre of $\alpha$ is $2$, we conclude that
$q$ is surjective and of degree $2$. So by the universal property of the quotient, we get
a map $E^{(2)}\to P$ over $E$, which is birational and finite, and thus by Zariski's main theorem,
it must be an isomorphism, establishing the second claim.

Comment: This looks lovely - defining the map of locally free sheaves by adjunction is pretty slick. Thanks for the nice answer!

Comment: @Hank Scorpio. You are welcome. Thank you for the interesting question.

Comment: Sorry, looking at this again I'm having a little trouble with the claim that the adjunction map is surjective by semicontinuity. Could you say a little more? (My best guess is that semicontinuity of $h^0$ and $h^1$ of $O(I(D))$ on the fibers imply that $R^1\alpha_*O(I(D))=0$ and $\alpha_*O(I(D))$ is locally free of rank 2, giving for any point $e\in E$ that $\alpha_*O(I(D))\otimes k(e)$ is isomorphic to the global sections on the fiber. But now I kind of fall apart - we could test surjectivity of the adjunction map by restricting to fibers, but I get stuck working with the map.)

Comment: @Hank Scorpio. As you write, one checks that the restriction of the morphism $\phi$ to each fibre of $\alpha$ is surjective. This follows from base point freeness, as explained above. But this implies that the restriction of $\phi$ to each point of $E\times E$ is surjective (since each point is contained in a fibre). Hence $\phi$ is surjective by Nakayama.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Ok, all the rest of the argument is great, but I am a bit stuck at checking the restriction of the morphism $\phi$ to the fiber. I know that the adjunction map is surjective on global sections, and if I knew that the restriction map gave a surjection of global sections of $O(I(D))$ to $O(I(D))|_{fiber}$ I'd win since the restriction to the fiber is globally generated. But I don't see how to argue that (there's lots of times restriction maps aren't surjective on global sections) - any pointers?

Comment: Oh, the restriction from global sections to the fiber can't be surjective - $O(I(D))$ has global sections $k$ (by Kunneth, for instance). So I guess I'd better spend some more time digging in to the restriction of the adjunction map to the fiber.

Comment: @Hank Scorpio. Yes: $O(I(D))$ is not globally generated on $E\times E$. It is only its restriction to a fibre which is. But this gives you the surjectivity of the adjunction map (together with semicontinuity and the vanishing of cohomology groups that I mention).